# osmdroid custom marker on map

Tags: android, marker, osmdroid

i'm using osmdroid 3.0.8 in my project, and creating custom markers on map. But in different resolutions of displays it seems very very large.
for example in mdpi it uses picture 48x48 and its ok, in xhdpi its 72x72 and its look very large.
I change  pictures in res/drawable for all resolutions and set all pic 48x48.
In mdpi and xhdpi(7"+) its ok, but at xhdpi 4,7" its looks bad.
here is code:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
OverlayItem o =new OverlayItem();   
o.setMarker(myIcon);
```